# Stochastic processes - Branching process - Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Consider the branching process with offspring distribution given by $\{p_n\}^\infty_{n=0}$. We change this process into an irreducible Markov chain by the following modification: whenever the population dies out, then the next generation has exactly one new individual. That is $P (X_{n+1} = 1|X_n = 0) = p(0, 1) = 1$. For which $\{p_n\}^\infty_{n=0}$ will this chain be null recurrent, recurrent, transient? The finite second moment of the offspring distribution can be assumed, i.e. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2p_n < \infty$.